# Virtuoso returning different float values from same resource

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

I don't understand why `Virtuoso SPARQL` is returning different float values (specifically, longitude and latitude) from the same resource.

This is my query ([link](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20dcterms%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20foaf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20geo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2003%2F01%2Fgeo%2Fwgs84_pos%23%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%3Fresource%20%3Flon%20%3Flat%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fsubcat%20skos%3Abroader*%20dbc%3AAirports_in_Libya.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fresource%20dcterms%3Asubject%20%3Fsubcat.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fresource%20geo%3Alat%20%3Flat.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fresource%20geo%3Along%20%3Flon.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fresource&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on))

```
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>

SELECT ?resource ?lon ?lat WHERE {
  ?subcat skos:broader* dbc:Airports_in_Libya.
  ?resource dcterms:subject ?subcat.
  ?resource geo:lat ?lat.
  ?resource geo:long ?lon.
}
GROUP BY ?resource
```

which returns a list of airports with their geographic coordinates. Yet few airports are listed multiple times. The reason is (probably) that `lon` and `lat` are sometimes returned with slightly different values from the same `DBpedia` page.

For example,

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/RAF_Gambut  23.9094 31.9095
http://dbpedia.org/resource/RAF_Gambut  23.9095 31.9095
http://dbpedia.org/resource/RAF_Gambut  21.8272 21.7061
```

I don't understand why since the [page](http://dbpedia.org/page/RAF_Gambut) actually only reports only one pair of coordinates...

```
geo:lat  31.951111 (xsd:float)
geo:long    24.503889 (xsd:float)
```

which doesn't appear anywhere in my result. Has it something to do with float rounding?

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick shows you that the numbers on the page that you are seeing are deceiving.

```
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>

SELECT ?resource (str(?lon) as ?long) (str(?lat) as ?latt) 
WHERE {
  ?subcat skos:broader* dbc:Airports_in_Libya.
  ?resource dcterms:subject ?subcat.
  ?resource geo:lat ?lat.
  ?resource geo:long ?lon.
}
GROUP BY ?resource
```

[image]

Often when you see something that looks exactly the same, but it isn't, it needs some further investigation. If you try filtering out the first line for the `http://dbpedia.org/resource/RAF_Gambut` resource, you can see that you only get one result:

```
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>

SELECT distinct ?subcat ?resource ?lon ?lat
WHERE {
  #?subcat skos:broader* dbc:Airports_in_Libya.
  ?resource dcterms:subject ?subcat.
  ?resource geo:lat ?lat.
  ?resource geo:long ?lon.
filter(?resource=<http://dbpedia.org/resource/RAF_Gambut>)
}
GROUP BY ?resource
```

[image]

As you see, you still have only one `?lon` and `?lat`. If you look closely there is no ?subcat that matches what you are extracting, and you are asking `SKOS` vocabulary to give you `broader` options. At this point if you dig deeper, you can see that some of the numbers are in scientific notation.

[image]

The way to get eliminate and harmonize the output is to eliminate scientific notation.

```
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>

SELECT distinct ?resource ?lonf ?latf 

WHERE {
  ?subcat skos:broader* dbc:Airports_in_Libya.
  ?resource dcterms:subject ?subcat.
  ?resource geo:lat ?lat.
  ?resource geo:long ?lon.

bind(xsd:float(?lat) as ?latf)
bind(xsd:float(?lon) as ?lonf)

}
GROUP BY ?resource
```

There are still a couple of resources with more than one longitude and latitude (e.g. `http://dbpedia.org/page/Gamal_Abdul_El_Nasser_Air_Base`) but they have more than one in the dbpedia page as well.

Comment: Where is the information coming from if is not listed in the http://dbpedia.org/resource/RAF_Gambut?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Does it answer your question?